# ¿Como hago una condicion con OnKeyPress en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito que cuando le den click al boton me cambio la funcion de especiales por la de solo numero

```js
function especiales(e) {
  tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

  //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
  if (tecla == 8) {
      return true;
  }

  // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros y letras
  patron = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
  tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
  return patron.test(tecla_final);
}

function soloNumero(e) {
  key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  teclado = String.fromCharCode(key);
  
  numero = "0123456789";
  especiales = ["8","9","37","38","46","13"];
  
  teclado_especial = false;
  
  for(var i in especiales){
    if(key == especiales[i]){
      teclado_especial = true;
    }
  }
  
  if(numeros.indexOf(teclado) == -1 && !teclado_especial){
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input placeholder="Buscar por Documento" class="form-control input-sm" id="documento" tabindex="1" name="documento" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" onKeyPress="return especiales(event)" readonly="readonly">
  
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id"clienteNew" class="btn btn-success input-sm" type="button" sytle="padding: 0;">
      <p style="padding: 4px;">Cliente Nuevo</p>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
var filter = 0;

function cambiarFiltro() {
  filter = filter === 1 ? 0 : 1; // Cambia entre 1 o 0;
}

function filtro(e) {
  switch(filter) { // Según el valor de filter se elije que función usaremos
    case 0: return especiales(e);
    case 1: return soloNumero(e);
    // case 2: return otraFuncion(e); // puedes crear más casos!
    // default: return funcionPorDefecto(e);
  }
}
```

Cuando presiones un botón que tenga `onclick="cambiarFiltro()"` la variable `filter` cambiara de 0 a 1 y viceversa.

Luego en el input hacemos:

```
<input onKeyPress="return filtro(event)">
```

Así, la función que se ejecutará dependerá del valor `filter`.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregarlo en el elemento html

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="funcion()">
```

o agregar un evento listener con js

```
document.getElementById("ID").addEventListener("keypress", funcion);
```

ambas ejecutarian la funcion

```
function funcion(){
   console.log("Prueba")
}
```